# Ruby next run in X minutes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron

I have a ruby on rails app, and there is a cron running in the background.
The cron job runs every 10 minutes on the 10 minutes, so 9:00, 9:10, 9:20, 9:30 and so on.
In my rails app, I want to show when the cron will next run.

So I will have, "Cron will next run at: 9:20PM"

I just can't figure out how to get this in ruby.

Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def next_10_minutes
  nxt = Time.now+(10-Time.now.min%10).minute
  nxt.strftime("%H:%M")
end

next_10_minutes
#=> "00:30"
```

or little more flexible and monkey patching

```
class Time
  def self.next_10_minutes
    self.now+(10-Time.now.min%10).minute
  end
end

Time.next_10_minutes.strftime("%H:%M")
#=> "00:40"
```

Comment: Actually the problem here is that in `00:40` it will return `00:40`, while it should return `00:50`. So you need just add 1 minute to current_time if you need. `self.now+(10-(Time.now + 1.minute).min%10).minute`

Comment: Very nice, but you don't display the "next run in X minutes" :)

Comment: I believe Andrew is not a total newbie ;)

Comment: Anyway this is the question :)

Comment: Thanks a huge amount, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: `(10-Time.now.min%10).minutes.from_now` might be more Rails like.

Comment: Wow all those monkey patching libraries are ugly. Too bad, while this language was quite awesome.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple:

- get the current minutes: `min = DateTime.now.min`
- round to the upper ten minute:

  ```
  nextTick = ((min/10.0).ceil*10)
  ```
- print the difference:

  ```
  diff = nextTick - min
  hour = DateTime.now.hour
  if nextTick == 60
      nextTick = 0
      hour = (hour + 1) % 24
  end
  print "Next run in #{diff} minutes (at #{hour}:#{nextTick})"
  ```

Try it here: http://codepad.org/5vxlg6kF

Comment: You don't need to `require 'date'` with Rails

Answer (score 0):

```
def next_tick(now)
    min10 = ((now.min / 10) + 1)*10
    if min10 == 60
        Time.mktime(now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour + 1, 0)
    else
        Time.mktime(now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour, min10)
    end
end

p next_tick(Time.now)
```